# What is the name of the texture in the Wunderlist Sidebar?

Tags: texture

I was using Wunderlist, and I was wonderling what the texture is that is used in the sidebar, as shown in this image:

[image: wunderlist screenshot]
<sup>Image courtesy of [ifrick.ch](http://www.ifrick.ch/2012/12/wunderlist-2-wird-richtig-schon/). [Click image for full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gloD.jpg)</sup>

It looks like some sort of fabric, but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Be careful now: Apple is discouraging such skeuomorphism with iOS 7 ;)

Comment: @plainclothes haha yes but I feel like I'm cheating by only knowing how to design flat interfaces and not also skeuomorphic.

Comment: @plainclothes Would you really consider that skeumorphism? If it is, it seems to be extremely subtle. I suppose it sort of looks like a thick piece of construction paper, but when I think of skeumorphism, I think of things more like the iOS newstand app, which is completely unnecessarily designed as a book shelf. On the note of Apple discouraging it, they went to some serious extremes with previous iOS's, such as the example I mentioned. Maybe their idea of going the other way will be a gradual turn from imitating a yellow note pad, or a book shelf.

Comment: Certainly this is a milder manifestation than some of Apple's garish attempts. Still it does feign the appearance of an office setting. Which I think they've done well, BTW.

Answer (score 11):

It does look like Linen or other kind of woven pattern. You can find a lot of such subtle (and free) patterns here: http://subtlepatterns.com/

Answer (score 2):

Looks to be a basic **Linen**-like texture to me. Used to mimic the texture of linen stock. Could possible be a **Laid** texture though. It's a bit hard to tell due to the angle.

Comment: I concur: Laid paper.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I bet if you add some noise to a layer in photoshop, then applied the motion blur horizontally, you'd be able to create it.